# Tutorial for My Yahoo Application

Tags: yahoo-api

I am looking for a tutorial to show how to create an application for My Yahoo!. Yahoo's tutorials are very confusing. (I wish their platform were as as simple as Google Gadgets!).

The application I want to create is very simple: a form with one field. You fill the form, press submit, and you get an additional field with your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications for My Yahoo are built with the Yahoo Application Platform. Start here for documentation and examples:
http://developer.yahoo.com/myyahoo/

In particular you may want to follow along with this Getting Started walk-through:
http://developer.yahoo.com/yap/guide/creating_open_app.html